# how do I Consume REST API dynamically through component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to refactor my component where it takes the data from a remote server as you can see below the mock API response. how can I restructure my component to fully depend on the API response, and fill the component based on their attributes where `_name` is my heading, and "data"` is our body data to fill the rest table alike

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Demo () {
    const [isModalOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
     const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
     const handleOnClick = async () => {
        try {
           const { data } = await axios.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
           setUsers(data);
   
           // Now that the data has been fetched, open the modal
           setModalIsOpen(true);
         } catch (err) {
           console.error("failed", err);
         }
     };
   
   
     return (
       <div className="container">
           <>
             {keys.map((key) => (
               <div className="col" key={key}>
                 <div className="row">{key}</div>
                   {arr[0][key].map((item) => (
                     <div className="row" key={item._id} onClick={() => handleOnClick(item)}>{item._name}</div>
                   ))}
               </div>
             ))}
           </>
           {isModalOpen && <Modal onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)} data={users}/>}
         </div>
     );
   }
```

API Response

{

```
   "count":39,
   "next":null,
   "previous":null,
   "results":[
      {
         "_name":"Collection",
         "data":[
            {
               "_id":"T1560",
               "_name":"Archive Data",
               "tags":[
                   "Collection"
               ],
               "subtitle":[
                  {
                     "subtitle_id":"T1560.001",
                     "subtitle_name":"Archive Utility",
                     "queries":[
                     ],
                  }
               ],
               "queries":[
                  
               ],
            }
         ]
      }
}
```

Comment: It's not super clear to me where your problem is. Looks like you have a fair bit of of progress. What are you stuck on?

Comment: how do I retrieve the api to build a prototype based on it?

Comment: Your question is 'how do I build an API?' It's a bit too broad for stack overflow. have you considered looking for some tutorials?